# Synchronise SharePoint List with its attachments in a local folder on my hard disk

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I am wondering if there is a way to synchronise SP List with its attachments in a local folder on my hard disk or a OneDrive folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly it is like what teylyn said. We cannot sync a SharePoint list with a local folder. In most cases list is synced with excel worksheet.

So as a workaround, I will say using a SharePoint Document library with columns holding required information is also a doable option. Instead of using attachments, just uploading the files you need and add all the fields you used in the list. Then you can sync the library using OneDrive with a local folder.

Comment: Alright, can you show me more ?

Answer (score 1):

No. Only document libraries can be synchronized with a local folder.

Don't shoot the messenger.